# What does the jg instruction do on classic Intel processors?

Tags: x86

For the code:

```
cmp $5, %eax
jg 804940f
```

This compares by doing %eax - $5 and then sets a flag(s) if it's greater, equal, or negative, correct? Then jg will proceed to that address if the flags dictate that %eax is greater than $5?

Comment: Please don't put the word "question" in the question title. Every question on StackOverflow is a question. Rather, give it a meaningful title, like "explanation of `cmp` assember instruction" or something like that.

Comment: The authoritative (if a bit hard to read) source is the [intel manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html). `CMP` is described on pg. 3-150 in Vol. 2A and `JG` on pg. 3-544. Beware of differences between the AT&T syntax used by GCC/GAS and the standard intel syntax used by the manual (which you can get with `.intel_syntax` btw).

Answer (score 4):

It does do a subtraction, but it does not keep the result. It then sets the flags accordingly. You are also correct about the second line, if its greater then it jumps, if not then it skips the jump and continues executing whatever is next.

EDIT: In case you are new to assembly, you may also find it helpful to have access to the contents of the flags register.  There are a few ways to do this in Intel assembly, if you need the lower 8 bits then you can do  lahf  which will load them into ah.  If you want the entire contents of the register, then you can use  pushf  and  popf.  I hope this helps.

Comment: The cmp instruction works by performing a subtraction of its second operand from its first, but only affecting the flags and not storing the result - I think that's what the OP was referring to by '%eax - $5'

Comment: Right, I just didn't want the OP to get that confused, I will clarify my answer.